# Testing all functions in a module for errors

Tags: python

This may be a dumb question, but charging boldly ahead anyway.

I have a library of about a dozen Python modules I maintain for general use. Recently, after advice found here on SO, I changed all of the modules so they are imported in the `import x as y` style instead of `from x import *`. This solved several problems and made the code easier to manage.

However, there was an unintended side effect of this. Many of the modules use Python builtin modules like `sys` or `os` to do whatever, and the way the code was previously set up, if I typed `import sys` in module `x`, and used `from x import *` in module `y`, I didn't have to `import sys` in module `y`. As a result, I took this for granted quite a lot (terrible practice, I know). When I switched to `import x`, this caused a lot of broken functions, as you can imagine.

So here's the main issue: because Python is an interpreted language, errors about missing modules in a function won't show up until a function is actually run. And because this is just a general-use library, some of these errors could persist for months undetected, or longer.

I'm completely prepared to write a unit test for each module (`if __name__ == "__main__"` and all that), but I wanted to ask first: **is there an automated way of checking every function in a module for import/syntax errors, or any other error that is not dependent on input?** Things that a compiler would catch in C or another language. A brief Google and SO search didn't turn up anything. Any suggestions are welcome and appreciated.

Comment: How could it possibly know what you *meant* to type. All it could know is syntax errors and runtime errors. It is up to the developer and unit tests to test that the functions actually behave as intended.

Comment: @Cyber well syntax errors are what I had in mind. If I give a variable a wrong name I don't expect any compiler on Earth to figure that out.

Comment: Surely your IDE already catches syntax errors when you try to run the program. What IDE are you using?

Comment: @Cyber right now all I'm using is a very basic text editor. The way our systems are set up, it's the easiest way of accessing them. I could use an IDE to edit things, but then I'd have to continually transfer files to the host machine where they're stored. I need to look into a better setup for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. [`PyFlakes`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes) will warn you about those most basic errors, and you should make sure it's integrated with your favorite text editor, so it tells you about missing imports or unused imports whenever you save the file.

PyFlakes will, amgonst other things, tell you about

- syntax errors
- undefined names
- missing imports
- unused imports

To just run PyFlakes on all your files in a directory, you can just do:

```
pyflakes /path/to/dir
```

One big advantage that PyFlakes has over more advanced linting tools like `PyLint` is that it does static analysis - which means, it doesn't need to import your code (which can be a pain if you've got some complex dependencies). It just analyses the abstract syntax tree of your Python source, and therefore catches the most basic of errors - those that usually prevent your script from having even a chance of running.

I should also mention that there is a related tool, [`flake8`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8), which combines PyFlakes with [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) convention checks and McCabe code complexity analysis.

---

There's PyFlakes integrations for every editor (or IDE) I know. Here's just a couple (in no particular order):

- [Sublime Text](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-pyflakes)
- [vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2441)
- [emacs](https://github.com/purcell/flymake-python-pyflakes)
- [TextMate](https://github.com/jehiah/pyflakes.tmbundle)
- [Eclipse / PyDev](https://github.com/itaiin/eclipse-pyflakes)

Comment: It looks like this is going to be something only a proper IDE can do, so I'll go along this route. Thanks!

Comment: I actually tried to make pretty much the opposite point :-) You don't need a full blown IDE for leveraging `PyFlakes` - it's so simple it can easily be integrated with any text editor I know of.

Comment: well we're using a proprietary text editor, so I don't know if it can be integrated. I can certainly try but my permissions are not what I'd like them to be. I'll look into adding it. Thanks!

Comment: Also, simple text editors (vim, sublime, text mate) is what I use every day at work for Python projects, even projects with huge frameworks and millions of LoC. I would actually advise against using large IDEs for Python development.